# Deploying an Azure Function with Visual Team Services Build and release server

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have a large solution with 50+ projects. Inside of that solution we have an Azure Function project using the new Visual Studio 2017 preview. Meaning its no longer using csx files, but using dlls. We can not use CI but would instead like to have the entire solution build on committing to a certain branch, which we have this portion set up. What Im wondering is how you package the azure function project and then manually release it using VSTS release. So far I've found nothing compatible or using the new Azure Function style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've set up our function app project to build and deploy with VSTS - we're doing an automatic release rather than a manual trigger but this should still point you in the right direction.

The steps to set up this up with VSTS are detailed in [this](https://www.joshcarlisle.io/blog/2017/5/17/visual-studio-2017-tools-for-azure-functions-and-continuous-integration-with-vsts) blog post.

Also, here's a link to the original discussion [issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/291) on Azure Function tooling github.

Comment: I am working with Dakota on this solution.  The one issue I am having is this zips all azure function projects into one single zip.  I have been trying for the last few hours to modify the template so it writes a new zip per project, as we have several Azure function projects.  However not matter what I try I cannot get the zip file to be named the project name. Below is an example of what I am trying:
/p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\$(MSBuildProjectName).zip" 

Any suggestion?

Comment: I haven't tried that scenario - ours is pretty basic right now, we have our functions project in a separate solution to the rest of the app so we just build that solution.  I see your query on github, hopefully someone there can help.

Comment: Will be spending all today and tomorrow to solve the issue. Thank you so much though, you definitely helped guide us in the right direction.

Comment: By following my idea of extracting the zip after build I am able to deploy each individual function.  It is a lot dirtier that I would like, but it works!  Thanks again. Your post directly lead to us solving this.

Comment: No problems mate, that's great that you got it sorted.

I'll probably end up needing a similar setup as we build out more functions.